# Adjusting the size the volume, using the same uislider but for multiple sounds

Tags: iphone, xcode, cocoa-touch, avfoundation

I have 10 sounds in a view. And one uislider

This is the code for 1 of the sounds.

```
- (IBAction)oneSound:(id)sender; {
    SystemSoundID soundID;
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"1" ofType:@"mp3"];
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path],&soundID);
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound (soundID);
    if (oneAudio) [oneAudio release];
    NSError *error = nil;
    oneAudio = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:&error];
    if (error)
        NSLog(@"%@",[error localizedDescription]);
    oneAudio.delegate = self;
    [oneAudio play];    


}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [volumeSlider addTarget:self action:@selector(updateVolume) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}



-(void)updateVolume {
    [oneAudio, twoAudio, threeAudio, fourAudio, fiveAudio, sixAudio, sevenAudio, eightAudio, nineAudio, tenAudio, elevenAudio, twelveAudio, thirteenAudio, fourteenAudio, fifthteenAudio, sixteenAudio setVolume:volumeSlider.value];
}
```

This is the current method I've tried and it doesn't work. Thanks for the help

Comment: What doesn't work about it? It crashes? It doesn't play any sound at all? You can only affect one sound's volume?

Answer (score 0):

In updateVolume you can't call on multiple instances by listing them like that. What you should do is put all of these audio players into an array and loop through each and `setVolume` on each object in the array.

Comment: How do I do that? Thanks very much

Comment: You have heard of NSArray? Well there is a NSMutableArray too which allows you to add objects to it after it has been created. So,MADD your audio players to this array. Then, use a for loop to change the volume of all of them to the same level.